# nginx multiple location directives all give 404 pages

Tags: nginx

I'm not used to Nginx yet...migrating from Apache2. I do not understand the location and root directives...I've read that root is best to use over alias...so, I made all roots absolute paths.

Server Block here:

```
index index.php index.html;
location = / {
        root /var/www/app;
}
location /chat/ {
        root /var/www/project1/chat;
}
location /kanban/ {
        root /var/www/kanban;
}
location ~ .php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
}
```

When I have root /var/www/app; outside of a location block will the main index.php work. However, when adding location blocks with root paths, all I get are 404 pages. I hope that it is not required to add PHP location blocks for each defined location, surely that is not needed right?

All I want is, for www.site.com to go to /var/www/app/index.php and www.site.com/chat/ to go to /var/www/project1/chat/index.php, etc. for each of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect mywebsite.com/chat to a different directory than the root of your website you would have something like the code below.

```
root var/www/app;
index index.html index.php;
location /chat/ {
    alias /var/www/project1/chat/;
       index index.php;

}
```